# Differentiability of a weak solution

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity, harmonic-functions

Let $d$ be a positive integer with  $d \ge 2$. We write $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1},x_d)=(\hat{x},x_d)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^d.$ The standard inner product and the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$ are denoted by $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $|\cdot|$, respectively.

Let $\Phi \colon \mathbb{R}^{d-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ a $C^\infty$-function with $\Phi(0)=0$. Define a domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ by
\begin{align*}
D=\{(\hat{x},x_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid x_d>\Phi(\hat{x})\}.
\end{align*}

We fix $R>0$. Let $h\colon \overline{D}\cap  B(0,R)  \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function such that $\int_{D \cap B(0,r)}|\nabla h(x)|^2\,dx<\infty$ for every $r<R.$ We assume moreover that for every $r<R$ and $f \in C_c^\infty(B(0,r))$,
\begin{align}
\int_{D \cap B(0,r)}\langle \nabla h(x) ,\nabla f(x)\rangle \,dx=0\tag{A}.
\end{align}
In words, $h$ is a  harmonic function  with Neumann boundary condition.

Define a bijective map $\phi\colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ by
\begin{align*}
\phi(\hat{x},x_d)=
(\hat{x},x_d-\Phi(\hat{x})).
\end{align*}
We write $\psi$ for the inverse map. Fix $r <R$. We set  $U=\phi(B(0,r))$ and  $U^{+}=\phi(B(0,r) \cap \overline{D} )$. For $x \in U^{+}$, we let  $u(x)=h(\psi|_{U^{+}}(x))$. Then, we have from  (A) that for any $f \in C_c^\infty(U)$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{U^{+}}\langle  A(x) \nabla u(x) ,\nabla f(x)\rangle \,dx=0.\tag{B}
\end{align*}
Here, $A \colon U^{+} \to \mathbb{R}^d \otimes \mathbb{R}^d$ is a symmetric matrix-valued function. In fact, there exists $\Lambda>1$ such that $\Lambda^{-1}|y|^2 \le \langle A(x)y,y \rangle \le \Lambda |y|^2$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $x \in U^{+}.$ Letting  $a_{i,j}$ be the $(i,j)$-th element of $A$, the map $x \mapsto a_{i,j}(x)$ is of $C^\infty$ class.

**My question**

We set  $U^{-}=\{(\hat{x},x_d)\mid (\hat{x},-x_d) \in U^{+} \}$, the mirror  reflection of $U^{+}.$ We alse set for $x=(\hat{x},x_d) \in U^{-},$
\begin{align*}
u(x)=u((\hat{x},-x_d)),\quad A(x)=A((\hat{x},-x_d)).
\end{align*}
Then, equation (B) implies that for every $f \in C_c^\infty(U^+ \cup U^-)$
\begin{align*}
\int_{U^{+}\cup U^{-}}\langle  A(x) \nabla u(x) ,\nabla f(x)\rangle \,dx=0.
\end{align*}
Then,  can  we  show  that the function $u$ is  smooth on $U^{+}\cup U^-$ or $U^+$?

Any elements of the coefficient matrix $A(x)$ is smooth outside  $\phi(B(0,r) \cap \partial D )$.